# Facing issue while tried to created login form in react

Tags: reactjs

Input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<div>
<Modal show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal} >
                <div className="blkOverlay">
                    {/* This is Login Form to log in to your profile */}
                    <div className="formContent modal-main">n>
                        <h2>Welcome Back <span>Brandon!</span></h2>
                        <form show={this.state.show} handleClose={this.hideModal}>
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                            <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" passwordToggle="true" iconShow="eye" iconHide="eye-blocked" />
                            <div className="passContent">
                                <div className="checkingPass">
                                    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"></input>
                                    <p className="passFont">Remember Password</p>
                                </div>
                                <p className="passFont">Remember Password</p>
                            </div>
                            <input type="button" name="button">Login</input>
                            <div className="social-media-button">
                                <input type="button" name="button">Sign in with Facebook</input>
                                <input type="button" name="button">Sign in with Google</input>
                            </div>
                            <p className="passFont">Don't have an account? <span>Create a account</span></p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {/* This is Sign up to create a account */}
                </div>
            </Modal>
          </div>
```

What is the proper way to create a form in reactjs with getting this error about the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put "Sign in with Facebook/Google" inside the input-tag. This is the reason why it is complaining about children. In React, a child is another tag inside a tag.

You should use:

```
<input type="button" value="Sign in with Facebook">
```

Comment: Thank you, you thought something new. :)